# Compare workbook and generate report with highlighted differences and additional column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two huge workbooks (old & new) of annual employee data and trying to compare. Each workbook has the same header and employees are in random order.
Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Use employee ID (in column D) as reference and compare if they’ve changed information, specially Physician (in column L).
2. Generate report highlight the different cell with added column (Change Information “Yes/No”) if there are changes or not.

Problem:
This code compare cell by cell only (took a lot of time) and not per employee id how could I insert here the looping of employee id? I am newbie in VBA. Any guidance on how I should go about this? Thanks.

```
Sub compare2Worksheets()
Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
Dim row As Long, col As Integer
Dim ws1 As Workbooks
Dim ws2 As Workbooks


Set report = Workbooks.Add

'range of Data1
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“Data1”)
With ws1.UsedRange
ws1row = .Rows.Count
ws1col = .Columns.Count
End With

'range of Data2
Set ws2 = myworkbook.Worksheets(“Data2”)
With ws2.UsedRange
ws2row = .Rows.Count
ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With


maxrow = ws1row
maxcol = ws1col
If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

'generate report
report.Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Activate
Cells.Clear
Range(“A1”) = “FirstName”
Range(“B1”) = “LastName”
Range(“C1”) = “DOB”
Range(“D1”) = “EmployeeID”
Range(“E1”) = “Address”
Range(“F1”) = “Emailadd”
Range(“G1”) = “Mobilenumber”
Range(“H1”) = “DeptID”
Range(“I1”) = “DeptName”
Range(“J1”) = “Position”
Range(“K1”) = “Status”
Range(“L1”) = “Physician”
Range(“M1”) = “Change InformationY / N”
erow = Data1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

'look for differences 
difference = 0
For col = 1 To maxcol
    For row = 1 To maxrow
    colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col)
    colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col)
        If colval1 <> colval2 Then
        difference = difference + 1
        'not matched display and highlight
        Cells(row, col) = colval1 & “ <> ” & colval2
        Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
        Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
        'to update “Change InformationY / N”
        Cells(row + 1, 13).Value = "Yes"
        Else
        Cells(row, col) = colval2
        Cells(row + 1, 13).Value = "No"
        End If
Next row
Next col

'saving report
If difference > 0 Then
Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
myfilename = InputBox("Enter Filename")
myfilename = myfilename & “.xlsx”
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myfilename
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How may rows is "huge" , more than 100,000 ?

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 around 5k employees

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following here:

First I would create an array for the EmployeeID and the rows I found them in both sheets.

For that I need to declare a RecordType (has to be defined at the beginning of the module, not in the procedure!)
I assume, that you have less than 1024 employees to handle, if more, simply use a higher value in the Dim-Statement.
I also assume, that the Employee-Id is a string, otherwise you have to use 'Long' or 'Integer' instead

```
Type EmpRowRec
   EmpId as string
   Row1 as Long
   Row2 as Long
End Type
Dim EmpRowArr(1 to 1024) as EmpRowRec, EmpRowCnt as integer
```

Then I would go through both sheets and search for the row with the data for an employee:

```
Dim CurRow as long, CurEmpRow as integer,EmpRowOut as integer
…
EmpRowCnt=0
For CurRow = 2 to ws1Row 
   Colval1=ws1.cells(currow,4).value
   EmpRowCnt=EmpRowCnt+1
   EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).EmpId=colval1
   EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).row1=CurRow
Next CurRow
For CurRow = 2 to ws2Row 
   Colval1=ws2.cells(currow,4).value
   EmpRowOut=0
   For CurEmpRow=1 to EmpRowCnt
      If EmpRowArr(CurEmpRow).EmpId=ColVal1 then EmpRowOut=0:Exit For
   Next CurEmpRow
   If EmpRowOut=0 then ' Employee is only in sheet 2
      EmpRowCnt=EmpRowCnt+1
      EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).EmpId=colval1
      EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).row2=CurRow
   else
      EmpRowArr(EmpRowOut).row2=CurRow
   End If
Next CurRow
```

Now you can go through the array and create your report:

```
Currow =1 'You already copied the head values
For CurEmpRow=1 to EmpRowCnt
   with EmpRowArr(CurEmpRow)
      If (.row1>0) and (.row2>0) then 'your result will show only employees in both sheets
         Currow=currow+1
         For col=1 to maxcol
            Colval1=ws1.cells(.row1,col).value
            Colval2=ws1.cells(.row2,col).value
            Report.cells(currow,col).value=colval1
            If colval1<>colval2 then report.cells(currow,col).interior.color=rgb(255,200,200)
         Next col
      End if
   End with
Next CurEmpRow
```

This method shall show you a generic way to solve such a problem (I have to deal very often with). For sure adaptions e.g. how to handle employees appearing only in one sheet, marking changes with low or high impact are needed, but here I can't help you since I don't know your exact requests.

Due to the fact, that I wrote this text only in word I could not test the fragments under VBA, so some small errors may occur. Please try to fix it.

Comment: Hi @Tdi Ger Thank you so much for answering my post. I've tried your code and incorporate it to my code.  The result is generated report with headers only and no data. What could be the issue? No runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code with your logic:

```
Type EmpRowRec
   EmpId As String
   Row1 As Long
   Row2 As Long
End Type

Sub compare2Worksheets()
Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
Dim row As Long, col As Integer
Dim CurRow As Long, CurEmpRow As Integer, EmpRowOut As Integer
Dim wbkA As Workbook, wbkB As Workbook
Dim EmpRowArr(1 To 1024) As EmpRowRec, EmpRowCnt As Integer

'get worksheets from the workbooks
Set wbkA = Workbooks("Data1")
Set ws1 = wbkA.Worksheets("Data1")
'range of Data1
With ws1.UsedRange
ws1row = .Rows.Count
ws1col = .Columns.Count
End With

Set wbkB = Workbooks("Data2")
Set ws2 = wbkB.Worksheets("Data2")
'range of Data2
With ws2.UsedRange
ws2row = .Rows.Count
ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With

maxrow = ws1row
maxcol = ws1col
If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

'generate report workbook
Set report = Workbooks.Add
report.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells.Clear
Range(“A1”) = “FirstName”
Range(“B1”) = “LastName”
Range(“C1”) = “DOB”
Range(“D1”) = “EmployeeID”
Range(“E1”) = “Address”
Range(“F1”) = “Emailadd”
Range(“G1”) = “Mobilenumber”
Range(“H1”) = “DeptID”
Range(“I1”) = “DeptName”
Range(“J1”) = “Position”
Range(“K1”) = “Status”
Range(“L1”) = “Physician”
Range(“M1”) = “Change InformationY / N”
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

'go through both sheets and search for the row with the data for an employee
EmpRowCnt = 0
For CurRow = 2 To maxrow  'ws1row
   colval1 = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 4).Value
   EmpRowCnt = EmpRowCnt + 1
   EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).EmpId = colval1
   EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).Row1 = CurRow
Next CurRow
For CurRow = 2 To maxrow  'ws2row
   colval1 = ws2.Cells(CurRow, 4).Value
   EmpRowOut = 0
   For CurEmpRow = 1 To EmpRowCnt
      If EmpRowArr(CurEmpRow).EmpId = colval1 Then EmpRowOut = 0: Exit For
   Next CurEmpRow
   If EmpRowOut = 0 Then ' Employee is only in sheet 2
      EmpRowCnt = EmpRowCnt + 1
      EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).EmpId = colval1
      EmpRowArr(EmpRowCnt).Row2 = CurRow
   Else
      EmpRowArr(EmpRowOut).Row2 = CurRow
   End If
Next CurRow

'go through the array and create your report

CurRow = 1 'You already copied the head values
For CurEmpRow = 1 To EmpRowCnt
   With EmpRowArr(CurEmpRow)
      If (.Row1 > 0) And (.Row2 > 0) Then 'your result will show only employees in both sheets
         CurRow = CurRow + 1
         For col = 1 To maxcol
            colval1 = ws1.Cells(.Row1, col).Value
            colval2 = ws1.Cells(.Row2, col).Value
            report.Cells(CurRow, col).Value = colval1
            If colval1 <> colval2 Then report.Cells(CurRow, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 200)
         Next col
      End If
   End With
Next CurEmpRow

If CurRow > 0 Then
Columns("A:Y").ColumnWidth = 25
myfilename = InputBox("Enter Filename")
myfilename = myfilename & “.xlsx”
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myfilename
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary as a lookup table for the row number of each ID on the old data sheet. Then scan down the new sheet comparing rows with the same ID. IDs that appear on the new sheet but not the old are tagged "added". Those on the old sheet but not the new are tagged "deleted".

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub compare2Worksheets()

    ' config
    Const COL_ID = "D"
    Const COLS = 12 ' header col A to L
   
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wbRep As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsRep As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Long, i As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim bDiff As Boolean, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    
    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     
    'range of Data1
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook ' or other
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Data1") ' old data
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Data2") ' new data

    ' build lookup from data1
    With ws1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_ID).End(xlUp).row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, COL_ID))
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate ID " & key, vbCritical, .Name & " Row " & i
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf Len(key) > 0 Then
                dict.Add key, i
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' format report sheet
    Set wbRep = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set wsRep = wbRep.Sheets(1)
    wsRep.Name = "Created " & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD HHMMSS")
    ws1.Range("A1").Resize(, COLS).Copy wsRep.Range("A1")
    wsRep.Cells(1, COLS + 1) = "Change InformationY / N"

    ' copare data2 new data to data1 old data
    ' copy diff to report
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws2
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_ID).End(xlUp).row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, COL_ID))
            wsRep.Cells(i, COL_ID) = key
            If dict.exists(key) Then

                 r = dict(key)
                 dict.Remove key ' remove

                 ' check columns in row
                 bDiff = False
                 For c = 1 To COLS
                     If .Cells(i, c) <> ws1.Cells(r, c) Then
                         With wsRep.Cells(i, c)
                              .Value = ws2.Cells(i, c) & "<>" & ws1.Cells(r, c)
                              .Interior.Color = 255
                              .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                              .Font.Bold = True
                         End With
                         bDiff = True
                     End If
                 Next
                 If bDiff Then
                      wsRep.Cells(i, COLS + 1) = "Yes"
                      n = n + 1
                 Else
                      wsRep.Cells(i, COLS + 1) = "No"
                 End If
            Else
                ' copy all
                .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, COLS).Copy wsRep.Cells(i, 1)
                wsRep.Cells(i, COLS + 1) = "Added"
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
 
    ' keys remaining
    Dim k
    With ws1
        For Each k In dict.keys
            r = dict(k)
            .Cells(r, 1).Resize(, COLS).Copy wsRep.Cells(i, 1)
            wsRep.Cells(i, COL_ID) = k
            wsRep.Cells(i, COLS + 1) = "Deleted"
            i = i + 1
            n = n + 1
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim s As String, yn
    wsRep.Columns("A:M").AutoFit
    yn = MsgBox(n & " lines differ, save report Y/N ?", vbYesNo, _
               Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"))

    If yn = vbYes Then
        s = InputBox("Enter Filename")
        wbRep.SaveAs Filename:=s & ".xlsx"
    End If
    wbRep.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, I tried your code and it works!  I thought an array will do but Dictionary works like magic. I just need to edit few things here and there but the logic is perfect. :) Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have overseen, that 'Report' is a workbook, not a sheet. PLease replace 'Report.Cells()' with 'Report.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells()'